# Overlapping between contours and fill colour shows when exporting svg in GIMP

Tags: inkscape, gimp, svg, png

I have made a bunch of images where one of the paths (heart) has an contour with a gradient applied. I selected the order: 1. Fill colour 2. contour 3. deco, so that I don't have this weird overlapping between the fill colour and the contour. The problem is that only the SVG preserves that. Once I export the image to PNG in GIMP I suddenly see the overlapping. This is unusual, since I've made a similar image with the same motif and there the overlapping issue didn't occur. How do I specify in the SVG the contour so that it won't overlap with the fill colour after exporting to PNG?

Exported SVG

[image: Overlapping contour and fill colour in PNG]

VS Screenshot of SVG in browser.

[image]

Comment: Try exporting the PNG from Inkscape instead.  Then you can open the PNG in GIMP.  I'm not sure if GIMP fully supports the SVG format, most likely just very simple SVGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paint-order` attribute/CSS property is *relatively* new and part of the still unreleased SVG 2 specification, so it's very likely that GIMP just doesn't support it.

Either duplicate your object in-place and only set the stroke on one copy and the fill on the other, stacking them accordingly in the z-order, or export as PNG directly from inside Inkscape, which will pretty much always give you the exact same output as you see it in Inkscape.

Comment: didn't try the solutions yet but it's good to know that it's a GIMP issue. Can Photoshop handle the paint order though?

Comment: @J.Doe I don't know about Photoshop, since I don't have it, but why do you insist on using a raster program to do a vector program's job? I really recommend just using Inkscape to render it and processing the resulting PNG from there.

Comment: I can export PNGs in Inkscape? I literally started using Inkscape like 5 days ago.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes. It has its own entry in the menu ('File → Export...') and even an icon in the main toolbar.